# Gnuplot histogram which shows in Y the count of occurences of a string

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot, in my current situation I would like to plot data like:

```
/test1.html
/test1.html
/test1.html
/test2.html
/test1.html
/test2.html
```

The histogram I would like to create is one which shows:
in Y the count
in X, one entry for each string found in the above data

so based on above data, the histogram should show

1. a bar for /test1.html reaching 4
2. a bar for /test2.html reaching 2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Gnuplot cannot do such preprocessing. Use an external tool for this. If you are on a unixoid system you can use e.g.

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set boxwidth 0.8
set style fill solid
set yrange [0:*]
unset key
plot '< sort data.txt | uniq -c' using 1:xtic(2) with histograms
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Christoph

now the only matter is that I have too many x values, and so they appear overlapped resulting unreadable, do you have some hints?
Thanks again

Comment: @Gamby Maybe not so short and elegant as Christoph's unixoid solution, but gnuplot _can_ do such preprocessing _platform-independently_: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/67710390/7295599