# Gnuplot: Creating a histogram with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I would like to create a histogram on the occurence of text from a single column dataset using gnuplot. I would like some help please. Example for the dataset is like:

```
UDP
TCP
TCP
UDP
ICMP
ICMP
ICMP
TCP
```

Comment: Single column or single row? How large is the dataset, approx. how many items?

Comment: Sorry, single column. I couldn't put it into a column form. Forgive the formating. The items are 10 unique items that make a up total of 3000 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are similar questions, e.g. [gnuplot automatic stack bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66587394/7295599),
however, still a bit different.
The following examples creates some test data.
If you know the keywords already and want to have them
in a certain order, skip the step of creating a unique list and define `Uniques = '...'` yourself. It might be advantageous to enclose the items into double quotes in case you have keywords which include spaces.

- create a unique list of your keywords.
- define a lookup function via (mis)using the sum function (check `help sum`)
- use the plot option smooth (check `help smooth frequency`) by taking the lookup index as x

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### histogram: occurrences of keywords
reset session

# create some random test data
myKeywords = 'UDP TCP ICMP ABC WWW NET COM FTP HTTP HTTPS'
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:3000] {
        print word(myKeywords,int(rand(0)*10)+1)
    }
set print

# create a unique list of strings from a column
addToList(list,col) = list.( strstrt(list,'"'.strcol(col).'"') > 0 ? '' : ' "'.strcol(col).'"')
Uniques = ''
stats $Data u (Uniques=addToList(Uniques,1),'') nooutput

N = words(Uniques)
Lookup(s) = (sum [_i=1:N] (s eq word(Uniques,_i) ? _idx=_i : 0), _idx)

set xrange [1:N]
set xtics out
set ylabel "Counts"
set grid x,y
set offsets 0.5,0.5,0.5,0
set boxwidth 0.8

set style fill transparent solid 0.5 border
set key noautotitle

plot $Data u (Lookup(strcol(1))):(1):xtic(1) smooth freq w boxes
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]